# Using IP Proxy with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, proxy, ip, vpn

How would one go about using another IP address to make API calls? I want to hide my original IP.

Maybe some vpn service or gem?

I am using an Amazon API gem but want to make sure I can't get traced to the usual IP that I use. I would like to be making requests from an IP that I can buy/lease, for example.

I have looked into this here: https://github.com/ankane/ip_anonymizer ...but not sure if this will do what I want it to do.

Any feedback or suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure ip_anonymizer does what you want, it looks like it only removes the last octet from an ip, and is ment to anonymize incoming traffic to your rails app overriding ActionDispach#request_id. From the aws gem it looks like they just use net::http you could 'monkey patch' a proxy wherever they use net::http, or you could run your program from a vps

Comment: If you totally want to be anonymous on internet. Use cascade proxy server from different region and make sure the proxy server you choose should not have good diplomatic relations with your country :P. This way you are kind of untraceable.

Comment: You guys said some solutions, but did not explain how... I really didn't understand how to accomplish that. How this Monkey Patch on the NET:HTTP should be done on this case? How can I use cascade proxy server from different region using Ruby? Some examples would be nice!